# filtering relational models inside django forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

i have a model which has a foreign key relation with two oder models one of them is 'level'.
the view knows in which level you are based on a session variable,
and then filter the lessons
this is the lesson model:

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
level = models.ForeignKey(Level,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
chapiter = models.CharField(max_length=200)
lesson = models.CharField(max_length=200)
skill = models.CharField(max_length=200)
vacations = models.IntegerField()
link = models.URLField(max_length=700,null=True,blank=True)
remarques = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
order = models.IntegerField()
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
state = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

now this is my cbv to create a new lesson:

```
class GlobalLessonView(CreateView):
model = Lesson
form_class = GlobalLessonForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('globalform')
```

and this is the form:

```
class GlobalLessonForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Lesson
    fields = '__all__'
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['subject'].queryset = Subject.objects.none() #change to .all() to see list of all subjects

    if 'level' in self.data:
        try:
            level_id = int(self.data.get('level'))
            self.fields['subject'].queryset = Subject.objects.extra(where=[db_name+'.scolarité_subject.id in( select subject_id from '+db_name+'.scolarité_levelsubject where level_id='+level_id+')'])
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            pass  # invalid input from the client; ignore and fallback to empty City queryset
    elif self.instance.pk:
        self.fields['subject'].queryset = self.instance.level.subject_set
```

one of the main conditions is to filter level by a session variable
but the form does not accept request.session
so is there any way to change the levels that shows up at the form from the class based view,or there any way to pass request.session to form.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to GlobalLessonView:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    """Pass request to form."""
    kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs.update(request=self.request)
    return kwargs
```

Then change the constructor definition in GlobalLessonForm to:

```
def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
```

Then you will be able to reference request.session in GlobalLessonForm.

Comment: thanks a lot it works exactly as i wanted thank you again @Greg Cowell